# How to call a JavaScript function with parameter in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a simple example to call a JS function when a button is clicked. In this code I used the onclick method, but I want to learn how to call the same method using jQuery instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#but").click(
        doubleSize($("#inpt").val()); // **maybe not correct here**
    );
});
function doubleSize(x)
{
    //some code make a number double size
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<input id="inpt" type="text">
<button id="but" type="button" onclick="doubleSize(document.getElementById('inpt').value)" >click me !!</button>
<div><span id="result"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are going to do a jQuery event handler there is no need to use the onClick attribute for the element. You are already listening for that event.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace

```
    $("#but").click(
      doubleSize($("#inpt").val()); // **maybe not correct here**
    );
```

with

```
    $("#but").click(function() {
      doubleSize($("#inpt").val());
    });
```

Now it should work. The trick is that `.click` function has callback function which controlls doings after click, and you now learned to use it.

Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mwx3w/).
Find more on [api.jquery.com/click](http://api.jquery.com/click).

Comment: They'll also need to remove the inline js.

Comment: You mean onclick method? Yes I did just to show how I did to work.

Comment: No, jQuery's alternative for `onclick` is `.click`. See my demonstrative JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwx3w/